# Why 24 hours to award a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I added a bounty on a question simply because I wanted to reward an answer. Why must I wait 24 hours before awarding the bounty??? It seems as though I should be able to award a bounty any time I choose.

I perhaps understand *some* reasoning as a need to slow a user down to allow other answers, but really, if a user wants to add a bounty and then award it 10 minutes later, why are they prevented from doing so? Especially where the "reward answers" is the option chosen for the bounty?

Comment: This question would be better suited on meta.

Comment: err... ain't this meta :)

Comment: the holy grail of stack's [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) but then you could always look through the 1200+ bounty questions there.

Comment: See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116072/should-the-24-hour-timeout-apply-to-bounties-awarded-for-exemplary-answer) and [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107282/i-want-to-award-a-bounty-to-an-existing-answer-should-i-have-to-wait-24-hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 24 hours period for awarding bounties is designed mainly to attract attention to a question, rather than recognizing someone's great answer. This is why there is a waiting period, it's because of the way the *bounties feature* was designed. Bounties are seen more as a last resort for question that either requires more research and effort or needs a last chance before it's forgotten.

From the [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116072/should-the-24-hour-timeout-apply-to-bounties-awarded-for-exemplary-answer) mentioned in the comments:

> The bounty system is specifically made to draw attention to a question
>   and rub people the right way into answering it. The reason there is a
>   period in which the bounty cannot be awarded is to allow people to
>   spend some time into providing a great answer -- which sometimes
>   requires some thought and research. If a bounty is awarded quickly, it
>   discourages other potentially better answers -- people would be
>   significantly less inclined to provide a great answer to a question
>   for which the bounty has already been awarded.
>
> Another reason for some seemingly unnecessary restrictions on the
>   bounty system (i.e. bounty amounts, maximum number of outstanding
>   bounties at any particular time, bounty times etc.) are there to
>   prevent abuse, for example continuously transferring some of your rep
>   to a buddy of yours.

So, **I think it's good to add bounties as a recognition of effort, but because they were designed with other uses in mind, there are limitations to it** (the 24 hours waiting period being the main one).

Comment: The only thing to add to this is - while a bounty's open on a question, the question is listed more prominently, and more people see it. So, if you think an answer is great, it's good to have the bounty open for a little while: so other users are more likely to see it, and more likely to benefit from that great answer.